# Objective C - UITextField Live Search an NSMutableArray and Output to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, nsmutablearray

Similar to the WhatsApp 'Add Participants' to a new group feature, in my app I have a UITextField where the user can begin searching for contacts which also have the app installed to add to a group chat.

I store all of the available contacts in an NSMutableArray searchableContacts with the following keys

"firstName"
"lastName"
"phoneNumber"

Using the following delegate method, I would like to check the current input in the UITextField and see if it matches either part of the firstName OR lastName in the searchableContacts array:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{

    // Check if the user input matches the beginning of either firstName or lastName in contactsArray. If so, output that user information to the tableView

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an NSPredicate to filter the array.

For example like this:

```
NSArray *users = @[
    [[User alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Test" lastName:@"Me"],
    [[User alloc] initWithFirstName:@"Fooo" lastName:@"bar"]
];

NSString *searchTerm = @"bar";
NSArray *filteredArray = [users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(User *user, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [user.firstName containsString:searchTerm] || [user.lastName containsString:searchTerm];
}]];

NSLog(@"Filtered values: %@", filteredArray);
```

searchTerm in your case would be the theTextField.text property value. Filtered array contains all matched contacts.

Cheers